# Command python2.7 not found with pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm using a VPS which has Python 2.6 installed.  However, I want to use Python 2.7. I've installed it and can see that it's installed because when I run `which python`, the response is `~/python/Python-2.7.2/python`.  I then tried to install a package via pip (`pip install sysconfig`) and from the error, I can see that my system is using Python 2.6:

```
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 959, in <module>
```

I then typed `whereis python` and the response was:

```
python: /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.6-config /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib64/python2.6 /usr/include/python2.6 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

So...it looks like I'm not accessing 2.7 as I thought.  I then tried:

```
python2.7 -m pip install sysconfig
```

and I'm getting a command not found error.  Might there be a Path that I need to add somewhere so that the command python2.7 can be found so that I can install packages to my Python 2.7 folder?

Comment: export 'pythonpath' environment variable and it's value should be the path to the python2.7 location

Comment: Note that `PYTHONPATH` should be in uppercase

Comment: I added: export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/python/Python-2.7.2/ . to my .bashrc file, and the whereis python is still pointing to 2.6.